# Generar JSON con muchos datos

Tags: php, json

estoy creando un archivo JSON, su contenido viene desde base de datos, todo funciona pero tengo mas de 1.000 registros y el archivo JSON queda vació pero si limito el sql con un LIMIT 100 el JSON se crea correctamente, ¿como puedo crear un archivo JSON con muchos datos?
Este es mi código:

```
<?php 
 $datos = "SELECT * FROM tabla"
 foreach ($datos as $key => $dato) {
            $data[$key] = [
                "contacto" => [
                    "contactid"=> $dato['contactid'],
                    "firstname"=> $dato['firstname'],
                    "lastname"=> $dato['lastname']
                ]
            ];
        }

file_put_contents('js/myjs.json', json_encode($data));
```

Comment: podrias probar antes de ejecutar tu scrip colocando esto `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');`

Comment: la consulta puede ser muy lenta y te generara un timeout, la respuesta puede ser muy grande y debes aumentar el memory limit, la devolucion del JSON puede esperar mas que lo deseado en el cliente puede ser configuracion en Apache, tu solicitud puede ser muy grande y dar error 401 en el servicio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre puedes generar tu `JSON` elemento a elemento, en lugar de intentar generarlo todo de golpe:

```
<?php
$datos = "SELECT * FROM tabla";
$fhandle = fopen( 'js/myjs.json', 'w' );
$first = true;

fwrite( $fhandle, '[' );

foreach( $datos as $key => $dato ) {
  if( $first != true ) {
    fwrite( $fhandle, ',' );
  } else {
    $first = false;
  }

  fwrite( $fhandle, '{"contactid":"' . $dato['contactid'] );
  fwrite( $fhandle, '","firstname":' . $dato['firstname'] );
  fwrite( $fhandle, '","lastname":' . $dato['lastname'] . '"}' );
}

fwrite( $fhandle, ']' );
fclose( $fhandle );
```

**Nota**: **No** lo he probado, pero, salvo cambios mínimos, debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

El tamaño de elementos en JSON está limitado solo por la memoria disponible o los tiempos de ejecución máximos del servidor.

Puede utliziar la siguiente función para obtener más detalles si es que ocurre un error:

```
json_last_error_msg();
```